# Error loading IBM cloud Db2-warehouse tutorial data

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

cloud-sql-database-master tutorial. Data file won't load. Subset of 200 queries loads but does not accurately display data.

Walking through the IBM Db2 tutorial, I created the db schema using cityschema.txt, No issue. I drop cities1000.txt for upload. I get a message that the modification date format is wrong. It is the same format and indicated in the walk-through document, except the db date format includes hh:mm. On one attempt I manually edited the date format for only date, no data loaded.
I took a subset of first 50 records to upload with and without the last field modified date. Uploaded values were corrupted, displaying ????. I tried loading 200 records only English language records, again corrupted data. Downloaded data as CVS to check if only a display problem, the CVS was with the corrupted data. I would delete the table and reload the data each time.

Comment: Which tutorial? What error message? How does a wrong date look like and what is the format you are setting it to?

Comment: There seems to be only one IBM Db2 tutorial. The date format is identical to that shown in the upload data screen. I suppose that someone familiar with the tutorial would know the UX and recognize the UI.

Comment: Link to the tutorial, so that someone who wants to help, can find it.